# Create a simple Login page using eclipse and mysql

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have created a simple login page in which user will give an username and password. After clicking on submit button it will show welcome user. But it is not giving any result
This is my index page

This is my index login page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String error_msg = "";
        Object error = request.getAttribute("error");
        if (error != null) error_msg = error.toString();
    %>
    <div id="Container">
        <div id="Header">
            <h1>Online File Management System</h1>
        </div>
        <a href="../index.html" target="_self">Home</a>
        <div id="Content">
            <div id="Login">
                <form action="login">
                    <table align = "center" bgcolor=#66CCFF>
                        <tr><td align = "left">Username:   </td>
                            <td rowspan="7" valign="middle">
                                    <font color="red"> <%= error_msg %> </font>
                                    <p>You can also Login using Google</p>
                                    <p class="Google"><input name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Login with Google Account"></p> 
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input name="username" type="text" size="30"></td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td align = "left">Password:</td></tr>
                        <tr><td><input name="password" type="password" size="30"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td align = "left">Forgot your password?</td></tr>
                        <tr><td align = "left">Remember me       <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox"></td></tr>
                        <tr><td align = "left"><input type="Submit" value="LOGIN"></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Footer">
            Copyright &copy; 2014 Office of the Vice Chancellor.
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Database conectivity page :

```
package org.form.login;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;

public class database {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public String validateUserLogin (String username, String password) throws SQLException{
        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;
        Statement statement = null;

        String fullname = "";

        String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onfms";
        String USER = "root";
        String PASS = "";
        String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE fldUser_Name = '"+
            username+"'          AND fldPassword = '"+password+"' ";
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USER,PASS);
            resultset = statement.executeQuery(QUERY);
        }   catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   finally {
            if (resultset != null)
                resultset.close();
            if (statement != null)
                statement.close();
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my login servlet page:

```
package org.form.login;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.form.login.database;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class login
 */
@WebServlet("/login")
public class login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "/main.jsp";
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password");
        if (user == null || user.length() == 0 ||pass == null || pass.length() == 0) {
            url = "/index.jsp";
            request.setAttribute("error", "Username & Password must not be empty.");
        }else{
            try {
                String fullname = new database().validateUserLogin(user, pass);
                request.setAttribute("fullname", fullname);
                if (fullname != null || fullname.length() != 0){
                    request.setAttribute("sucess", "Sucessfull Connection");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        ServletContext context = getServletContext();
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

This is my final Page where I display my result

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Desk Board</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello
<%
    String sucess_message ="";
    Object sucess = request.getAttribute("sucess");
    if (sucess != null ) sucess_message = sucess.toString();
%>
<%= sucess_message %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, your app have to know somehow what form action="login" means.

Comment: I couldn't get it. Will you please help me I am new t o JAVA and this is my first page developing in java.

Comment: I would suggest instead of the two attributes `error` and `sucess` just use one `status` attribute and store in it either "error" or "success" (two c's) and do an if-statement on that in the JSP you forward to.  Also `String status = (String) request.getAttribute("status");` should be sufficient. You don't have to pull as an object, check for null, then do .toString(), because you stored it as String to begin with, so you can just type-cast.

Comment: You should specify method. `<form action='./login' method='get'>`

Comment: Seems like my sql is not retrieving any information from the database because with wrong username and password also i can get through.
Is there any link where I can get a step by step help

Answer (score 4):

use this code it is working

// index.jsp or login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="login" method="post">
Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password : <input type="password" name="pass"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

// authentication servlet class

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class auth extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public auth() {
            super();
        }
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

            String sql = "select * from reg where username='" + username + "'";
            Connection conn = null;

            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Exam",
                        "root", "");
                Statement s = conn.createStatement();

                java.sql.ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
                String un = null;
                String pw = null;
                String name = null;

            /* Need to put some condition in case the above query does not return any row, else code will throw Null Pointer exception */   

            PrintWriter prwr1 = response.getWriter();               
            if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()){
                prwr1.write("<h1> No Such User in Database<h1>");
            } else {

/* Conditions to be executed after at least one row is returned by query execution */ 
                while (rs.next()) {
                    un = rs.getString("username");
                    pw = rs.getString("password");
                    name = rs.getString("name");
                }

                PrintWriter pww = response.getWriter();

                if (un.equalsIgnoreCase(username) && pw.equals(pass)) {
                                // use this or create request dispatcher 
                    response.setContentType("text/html");
                    pww.write("<h1>Welcome, " + name + "</h1>");
                } else {
                    pww.write("wrong username or password\n");
                }
              }

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: This works great. I just had to add a missing closing curly brace } to the `if(!rs.isBeforeFirst())` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You Can simply Use One Jsp Page To accomplish the task.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
        String username=request.getParameter("user_name");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        String role=request.getParameter("role");
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/t_fleet","root","root");
            Statement st=con.createStatement();
            String query="select * from tbl_login where user_name='"+username+"' and password='"+password+"' and role='"+role+"'";
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
            while(rs.next())
            {
                session.setAttribute( "user_name",rs.getString(2));
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3000);
                response.sendRedirect("homepage.jsp");
            }
            %>



        <%}
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            out.println(e);
        }
    %>

</body>
```

I have use username, password and role to get into the system. One more thing to implement is you can do page permission checking through jsp and javascript function.

Comment: Why do you close and reopen the scriptlet if you aren't printing html between?

Comment: The code was from my web application. There was some code between. But for sake of giving answer, I removed it and made it simple. I have done permission checking on same page so I removed it.